# Upload file to server, then attach to email and send in one php file

Tags: php, email, upload, attachment

I've managed to make a script, with my poor php skills, that upload an image to a folder on my webserver. I now want the script to send an email with the image attached after it's uploaded.

This is my script. Maby my problem is that the email is sent before the file is uploaded completely. it worked one time with a small image.. But now nothing happens... (exept the file is uploaded...)

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
$new_image_name = "image".rand(10, 20).".jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/home/virtual/domain.com/public_html/upload/".$new_image_name);

//define the receiver of the email 
$to = 'sender@domain.com'; 
//define the subject of the email 
$subject = 'Upload: '.$_GET["album"]; 
//create a boundary string. It must be unique 
//so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash 
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n 
$headers = "From: reciver@domain.com\r\nReply-To: reciver@domain.com"; 
//add boundary string and mime type specification 
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\""; 
//read the atachment file contents into a string,
//encode it with MIME base64,
//and split it into smaller chunks
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('upload/'.$new_image_name))); 
//define the body of the message. 
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering 
?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>" 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!! 
This is simple text email message. 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h2>Hello World!</h2> 
<p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p> 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: application/jpg; name="attachment.jpg"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
Content-Disposition: attachment  

<?php echo $attachment; ?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

<?php 
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer 
$message = ob_get_clean(); 
//send the email 
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed"; 
?>
ge is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed"; 
};
?>
```

Comment: have you tried attaching the files, sending, then moving them? I suggest using phpMailer class to send email and make your life easier.

Comment: So what you say, is that i can send the file from the temp area on the server, then move or delete it after that...

Comment: Hmm i think i should re-evaluate my approach for this task. What i really need is just attaching and sending the file. no need to have it placed on the serverr. Ill be back ;)

Comment: @MartinLyder: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have rolled back the edit adding an answer to the question itself. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site and thus a question should be a question and an answer an answer. Please post [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11985558/2) as an answer instead.

Comment: Ahh ok! Thanks... To much redbull, could not wait the 8 hours bedre i could add a answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little logic help from Waygood. I found that i could move the file after attaching and sending it. I found this script working for me: http://netsperience.org/content/blog/attach-a-file-email-with-php-code-actually-works

And with my modifications it now works like a charm!

```
print_r($_FILES);

$new_image_name = "image".rand(10, 20).".jpg";
$email_to = "reciver@domain.com"; // The email you are sending to (example)
$email_from = "sender@domain.com"; // The email you are sending from
$email_subject = "Upload: ".$_GET["album"]; // The Subject of the email
$email_txt = "the body text"; // Message that the email has in it
$fileatt = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]; // Path to the tmp file
$fileatt_type = "image/jpeg"; // File Type
$fileatt_name = "upload.jpg"; // Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment
$file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
$data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
fclose($file);
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers="From: $email_from"; // Who the email is from (example)
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
$email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $email_txt;
$email_message .= "\n\n";
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
$email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
" name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
$data . "\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

mail($email_to,$email_subject,$email_message,$headers);

if (mail($email_to,$email_subject,$email_message,$headers)) {

       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/home/virtual/domain.com/public_html/upload/".$new_image_name);

    } else {
       echo "[B]email could not be sent[/B]";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use any mailing library instead like phpMailer

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

this will give you more control over email sending.

Comment: I thought about using phpmailer and had it installed, but then thought it was a bit overkill, for this "simple" task. And i think i will end up asking the same question here. how to first upload a filen then attach and send it to an email :)

Comment: Sir,help needed! Please check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999860/changing-codeigniter-site-from-http-to-https-site-not-working/11999986#11999986)