# Changing Codeigniter site from http  to https site - not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, https

I have a codeigniter site ,that working perfectly when it is in `http`.

Then our client moved the site to new server which have the `https` security.

That means now the site url is `http://mysite.com`.

But now my site is not working correctly...

What is the reason for that?

That is my codeigniter site not working in `https`.

It just display the home page ,and no jquery effects etc are not working..

I already changed the `base_url` in config.php as `https://mysite.com`.

Comment: try this link http://sajjadhossain.com/2008/10/27/ssl-https-urls-and-codeigniter/

Comment: i think you should use `.htaccess redirect`

Comment: @ Bhuvan , in `application` directory there have an htaccess file and it have contas as : `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} `

Comment: then that should do it! did it work?

Comment: @ Bhuvan , it is not working.i have one doubt.the .htaccess file is in application folder of root folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function redirectToHTTPS()
{
  if($_SERVER['HTTPS']!="on")
  {
     $redirect= "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
     header("Location:$redirect");
  }
}
```

Comment: @MariyaDavis in your controller.

Comment: @ Bhuvan, it is not working....In default controller i pasted your code..Then i got one error in bug as: `The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.`

Comment: @MariyaDavis i think you dont have ssl. Try this `@$_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on"` and report the output

Comment: @MariyaDavis check your root config.php and tell me if there is anything about `https` in `function __construct()`

Comment: @ Bhuvan , the root config.php means system/core/config.php or wich file?In root folder there have no config.php file in codeigniter2.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15450/discussion-between-mariya-davis-and-bhuvan-rikka)

Comment: sorry. i mean `system/core/config.php`

Comment: @ Bhuvan , i got a clue here,i deleted everything in the view page and just create a link and its href is same as the href of that red button .Then the link is working...

Comment: @ Bhuvan , ok bhuvan now i can handle it..if any help i needed how can i depend you?

Comment: @ Bhuvan, now i can manage the problems,but if any complications occure how can i get your support?If i post comments about my futre doubts here ,will you see this?

Comment: @ Bhuvan ,in my user regisistration form i had a recaptcha,so now i tried to do a user registration but it displays:`Could not open socket`.So how can i solve this?

Comment: @MariyaDavis you said that your server is changed,right. that is causing the issue. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232639/could-not-open-socket)

Comment: @MariyaDavis that is a network problem between the servers as said in the link. check the answer to get an idea about the problem